# Laravel 5.5 eloquent cartesian

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

What I'm trying to accomplish, I believe, are cartesian results based upon related models.  I want to do this with eager loading.

My eloquent query looks like this:

```
$results = PartBasePart::whereIn('id', array(1,2,3,4,5))
                       ->with('materials')
                       ->with('profiles')
                       ->get();
```

And is yielding results of:

```
+Collection
    PartBasePart - Model
        +Collection
            Material - Model1
            Material - Model2
            Material - Model3
            Material - Model4
            Material - Model5
        +Collection
            Profile  - Model1
```

**What is desire is:**

```
+Collection
    PartBasePart - Model
        +Collection
            Material - Model1
                +Collection
                    Profile  - Model1
            Material - Model2
                +Collection
                    Profile  - Model1
            Material - Model3
                +Collection
                    Profile  - Model1
            Material - Model4
                +Collection
                    Profile  - Model1
            Material - Model5
                +Collection
                    Profile  - Model1
```

How is this possible?  Can I get an instance of 'Profile - Model1' inside of each Material collection?

The models are defined as follows:

#### PartBasePart

```
class PartBasePart extends Eloquent
{
    public function materials()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Material::class)
                    ->withPivot('id');
    }

    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Profile::class)
                    ->withPivot('id');
    }
}
```

#### Material

```
class Material extends Eloquent
{
    public function partBaseParts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\PartBasePart::class)
                    ->withPivot('id');
    }

    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Profile::class)
                    ->withPivot('id');
    }
}
```

#### Profile

```
class Profile extends Eloquent
{
    public function materials()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Material::class)
                    ->withPivot('id');
    }

    public function partBaseParts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\PartBasePart::class)
                    ->withPivot('id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$results = PartBasePart::whereIn('id', array(1,2,3,4,5))
                   ->with('materials.profiles')
                   ->get();
```

You want to tell Eloquent that you want the profiles related to the materials ('materials.profiles') rather than the profile related to the PartBasePart. Your original query's `with`s were the equivalent of `with(['materials', 'profiles'])`.

Comment: Great point!  I've tried that but eloquent returns back all the 'profiles' that are associated to 'materials'.  What I need to have are the 'profiles' that are associated to the 'materials' and are constrained by the 'PartBasePart.id' array

Comment: It's possible `->wherePivotIn('materials.profiles.partbaseparts', array(1,2,3,4,5))` added before `get()` could make this work. at least it's a place to start.

Comment: If I'm reading your suggestion right I should have this.
```PartBasePart::whereIn('id', array(1,2,3,4,5))->with('materials.profiles')->wherePivotIn('materials.profiles.partbaseparts', array(1,2,3,4,5))->get();```

Inside of tinker, this is what I get.
```Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot_in' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from 'part_base_parts' where 'id' in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and 'pivot_in' = materials.profiles.partbaseparts)'```.   

Any idea why pivot_in is being called?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was suggesting. I guess that wasn't it, though. :)

At this point I'd start trying to construct a SQL query that achieved what I wanted and working backwards from there. Either that or look at filtering the results.

Comment: Ultimately, that's what I ended up doing.  Since my logic was very procedural, except the models change, I ended up writing two queries.  First query pulled in all the ```materials``` that I wanted.  I performed a foreach loop on the results and on the inside performed another query on ```profiles```.  Upon each one those results, I added to a dynamic property in the the ```materials``` collection.  I ended up getting where I needed to be, but not the way that I wanted.  Oh well.  It's time to get crackin' and lay some code down.